# Xcode storyboard class has no module

Tags: swift, xcode, module, storyboard

I have a project with two targets A and B.

When I open my storyboard and select one scene in particular and navigate to 'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > 'Module',

there is a single blank entry in the drop down (the drop down does not display A or B). When I select the blank entry the drop down shows "None". This is a problem because it causes my program to crash when attempting to use the scene.

If I select 'Inherit module from target', the correct target displays under 'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > 'Module', however my program will still crash when attempting to use the scene.

The class itself is found in the type-ahead of the 'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > 'Class' textbox.

The name of the class is SWRevealController.m (which is an obj-c file) whereas most of my project is in swift.

A and B appear as selectable in every other scene under 'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > Module. I can also select 'inherit module from target' for those scenes and the program does not crash.

Other things I have tried:
*manually deleting and re-adding the SWRevealController.m under 'Build Phases' > 'Compiled sources'
*making a new storyboard and putting view controllers in from scratch.

The main.storyboard itself is part of both targets.

Comment: Have you created a `BridgingHeader` if you're using Objective-C files in your Swift project?

Comment: yes. I have a bridging header called bridge.h - I made the bridge.h before I cloned my project into two different targets, so idk if that matters

Comment: Your bridging header file should be `YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` not a random name. And you should import your ObjC libraries/Classes in there

Comment: ok. I don't know that that matters because it works fine (at least before creating two different targets), but I will create a new bridging header from scratch and not rename it to 'bridge.h' this time

Comment: Hi, I tried making a new bridging header (no compilation errors with the previous header or the new one. The new bridging header is called $AppName-Bridging-Header.h). Under 'Project' > 'Build Settings' > 'Swift Compiler - General' > 'Objective-C Bridging Header', I changed for the project and both targets A and B, to read '$appName-Bridging-Header.h' (it used to read bridge.h). I tried restarting X Code however the 'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > 'Module' still shows a single blank entry.

Answer (score 2):

OK, what I did that worked for me (which I should not have had to do but it works) was 4 things.

1. Go into the SWRevealViewController.m and add

```
    @class SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController;
```

To make the seguesetcontroller available for step #2.

2. Make a swift file that inherits from the objective-C classes (and do nothing else)

```
    import Foundation
    
    final class MyRevealViewController : SWRevealViewController
    {
      
    }
    
    final class MyRevealViewControllerSegueSetController : SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController
    {
      
    }
```

3. Go into my storyboard and change the class from `SWRevealViewController` to `MyRevealViewControllerSegueSetController`. At this point, the different targets A and B appear in the drop down under  'identity inspector' > 'custom class' > 'Module'.
4. I needed to change the Segue classes used in my storyboards from `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` to `MyRevealViewControllerSegueSetController`

Answer (score 0):

Odd enough, I selected one of the presented options from `class` dropdown and it enabled itself.

[image]